# Add and use an external library in Cmake for a Qt project

Tags: c++, cmake, qt5

I am trying to make use of [libmaia](https://github.com/wiedi/libmaia) in a Qt project using C++.

Since I'm from a JavaScript background, all of the answers regarding setup of an external library in Qt are going way over my head.

This library libmaia has docs for installation but it only points out how to install using qMake. I am using CMake in my project.

What I've tried:

- Cloned the project and copied the files over to the Qt project
- Tried adding a find_library() call in the CMake, which fails.
- So, I tried the target_link_libraries() entry for the project.

My understanding is that I am missing the build step of the project to generate a **.a** or a **.so** file.

How do we conclude that an external library will only work with QMake or CMake?

Any help / resources to read up / GitHub examples of the setup would be gladly appreciated.

Also, if someone can simplify my understanding of the setup procedure, that would be great! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

*"...  and copied the files over to the Qt project"* - No, don't. Remove them from there. You should build and install the library separately.

```
git clone git@github.com:wiedi/libmaia.git
cd libmaia
```

Then, the instruction to build is to do `qmake` + `make` - but that fails for me (with Qt6), so I used `cmake`.

If you build `libmaia` for yourself only, you can install the library in a place where you store other libraries you build. It's common to place them in a directory named `.local` in the home directory. So `mkdir ~/.local` (or something like `mkdir %USERPROFILE%\source\repos\.local` on Windows) if you don't have such a directory already, then:

```bash
mkdir build
cd build
cmake --install-prefix ~/.local ..
# Windows: cmake --install-prefix %USERPROFILE%\source\repos\.local
make -j
cmake --install .
```

<sup>(Note: It's really `..` for the first `cmake` and `.` for the second)</sup>

Possible output of the `cmake --install .` command:

```
-- Install configuration: ""
-- Installing: /home/ted/.local/lib/libmaia.a
-- Installing: /home/ted/.local/lib/cmake/libmaia/libmaiaTargets.cmake
-- Installing: /home/ted/.local/lib/cmake/libmaia/libmaiaTargets-noconfig.cmake
-- Installing: /home/ted/.local/lib/cmake/libmaia/libmaiaConfig.cmake
-- Installing: /home/ted/.local/lib/cmake/libmaia/libmaiaConfigVersion.cmake
-- Installing: /home/ted/.local/include/maia/maiaFault.h
-- Installing: /home/ted/.local/include/maia/maiaObject.h
-- Installing: /home/ted/.local/include/maia/maiaXmlRpcClient.h
-- Installing: /home/ted/.local/include/maia/maiaXmlRpcServerConnection.h
-- Installing: /home/ted/.local/include/maia/maiaXmlRpcServer.h
```

In your own project's `CMakeLists.txt` (replace `/home/ted/.local` or `C:/Users/Ted/source/repos/.local`) with the path to your `.local` directory:

```
...
find_package(Qt5Network CONFIG REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5Xml CONFIG REQUIRED)
find_package(libmaia CONFIG REQUIRED PATHS /home/ted/.local)
# or C:/Users/Ted/source/repos/.local

add_executable(Foo main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(Foo libmaia::maia Qt5::Network Qt5::Xml)
```

Then in your code:

```
#include "maia/maiaXmlRpcClient.h"
// and / or
#include "maia/maiaXmlRpcServer.h"
```

Comment: By "If you build this for yourself only...", do you mean to ask if I'm running this application only on my device? I need to build a final executable and distribute to a good number of operators.
Also, I forgot to mention that I work on a windows 11 device.

Comment: @snipedown21 No, I meant if you will be the only user of `libmaia`. The final executable will be relocatable. If you're on Windows, the actual library name may be `maia.lib` or `maia.dll` if it's built to be dynamic. If `maia.dll` is built, you need to include `maia.dll` when you distribute your executable.

Comment: @snipedown21 I made the `CMakeLists.txt` file a little cleaner so you shouldn't need to think about the actual library name.

Comment: @snipedown21 If you run into problems following my guide, please let me know and I'll try to improve it.

Comment: I am running into errors like :
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:10 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Network" with
  any of the following names:

    Qt5NetworkConfig.cmake
    qt5network-config.cmake
while running the cmake install command. Any suggestions?

Comment: @snipedown21 It seems like you didn't install Qt5 where `find_package` searches. You can try changing `libmaia`s `CMakeLists.txt` and add the paths to your Qt5 installation, just like I showed above: `find_package(Qt5Network CONFIG REQUIRED PATHS C:/path/to/qt5/...)` etc.

Comment: I got that to work. Now with make, I am getting the following error:

make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247324/discussion-between-snipedown21-and-ted-lyngmo).